# Python metaclass 'nmspc' what does it mean?

Tags: python, python-2.7, metaclass

I've seen 'nmspc' being used in the `__init__` and `__new__` methods of a metaclass in Python. What does 'nmspc' stand for?

```
class SimpleMeta1(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, nmspc):
        super(SimpleMeta1, cls).__init__(name, bases, nmspc)
        cls.uses_metaclass = lambda self : "Yes!"
```

Comment: **Namespace**: Dictionary containing the attributes of the class.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments of `__init__` and `__new__` are the same as the parameters of the `type` function:

```
type(name, bases, dict) -> a new type
```

where the third parameter contains a dictionary with all methods or class variables defined inside the `class`-Block. As this is the "Namespace" of the class, someone might name it `nmspc`, for me, a name should be clear to the reader, so some vowels would be nice.